# Going from IE8 to IE10 in HP QTP 11?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, migration, internet-explorer-10, qtp, hp-uft

We have changed from IE8 to IE10 and there are many Test scripts which are made in QTP 11 using IE8. So knowing that HP QTP 11 does not support IE10, I had some queries regarding the migration:

1. If we change to UFT what will be the changes in the object repository properties? e.g. will the micclass of an object change?
2. If there is any such change is there any standard way to go about this process?

Also any other suggestions on this migration will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**QTP 11 does not support IE10**

If we change to UFT what will be the changes in the object repository properties? e.g. will the micclass of an object change?

```
No. Upgrading QTP to UFT will not affect the script. Your script should run fine.
The same is applicable for IE upgrade as well.
```

Comment: Does that mean the same object repository from IE8 and QTP 11 will work with UFT for IE10 without any editing?

Comment: Yes. I too upgraded from QTP to UFT 1.5 years ago. It worked fine. I did not face any issues. But scripts created in UFT might not work in QTP.

Comment: Yes that is fine. We will never come back to QTP now onwards. Thanks for all the responses. :)

Comment: - Have you tried automating PDF form validation using UFT? If yes, are the objects recognized as Winobject or some other type?

Comment: In my project, we generate hundreads of PDFs and do the comparison. For this, I created a VB.net dll. QTP/UFT's text recognition method is not reliable.  Ok, for your question, if the PDF gets opened in IE, it should get recognized as ActiveX object. Please ensure that ActiveX addin is selected in your test

Comment: Thank u for your input. I will post another query if i have any detailed queries

Comment: Hello Vinoth, We have started using UFT and we are facing a small challenge. We have a framework on the shared drive and these framework files are used by the local scripts. Also for the scripts in Quality center we have the framework files placed there. Then problem we face is for the scripts on the local drive UFT crashes as soon as the run begins. Where as the script in Quality center work fine.

Comment: @Noob Could you please create a separate question in this forum with some more details/screenshots if possible?

Answer (score 0):

Scripts created in QTP 11 will work fine in UFT. But remember 'backward compatibility' is not possible. That means once scripts are converted to higher version then it wont run back on the previous version. So better have a back up before you move to UFT.